# Accessibility issue in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

In my app we have taken a scrollview with paging enabled inside that i have added multiple custom views which can have multiple individual elements which are all accessible. Now the issue is when accessibility is on and i try to traverse all the elements via right swipe gesture.

Observation: when it comes to last element of first custom view and i perform right swipe gesture it does not jumps the focus to next custom view elements. Any idea how i can make it happen?

I followed [voice over can only see a page of a uicollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448279/voice-over-can-only-see-a-page-of-a-uicollectionview/13473926#13473926) but here there are using collection view and individual elements inside UICollectionViewCell are not accessible

Comment: Are you looking for a psychic?  Or are you trying to save time by not showing code?

Comment: Which is happening: a) not focusing and speaking the element b) not visually scrolling to the element?

Comment: Not focusing on the element which partially visible on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Using paging with a scrollview, the UIPageControl handles movement between the subviews. You really should just leave this control as the accessibility component for navigation as users are familiar with how it works.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol